# jquery mobile - how to use listview data-filter for two data-sets?

Tags: javascript, ajax, listview, filter, jquery-mobile

I have a JQM page with two *data-role="listview"*. They both share the same data-set, one listview is text-only, the other one also includes icons.

I want to use the *data-filter="true"* option on both listviews, but only with one filter, which updates both listviews.

I'm clueless on how I could do this, so any hints are greatly appreciated.

Here's what I have:

```
 <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-divider-theme="c">
    <li data-role="list-divider">B</li>
    <li><a href="#profile" data-transition="slide"><img src="loc/icons/brandSprite.png" class="ui-li-icon">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile" data-transition="slide"><img src="loc/icons/brandSprite.png" class="ui-li-icon">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile" data-transition="slide"><img src="loc/icons/brandSprite.png" class="ui-li-icon">Three</a></li>
    ...

 <ul data-role="listview" class="iconList">
    <li data-icon="false"><a href="#profile" data-transition="slide"><img src="img/brands/icon_one.png" /><h3>One</h3></a></li>
    <li data-icon="false"><a href="#profile" data-transition="slide"><img src="img/brands/icon_two.png" /><h3>Two</h3></a></li>
    <li data-icon="false"><a href="#profile" data-transition="slide"><img src="img/brands/icon_three.png" /><h3>Three</h3></a></li>
    ...
```

The first list has the filter, which should filter both the first and second list.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both are separate lists. data-filter="true" is for filtering in one list only, where it is set.
what u can do is a hack maybe. put data-filter=true in both. then after the list is refreshed, hide the filter on the second list. (display:none). Now put an event handler which types on the second filter field whatever u type on the top one.  
This will work but is not recommended. I suggest instead of using data-filter="true" u implement your own filtering mechanism for this. 
Or just put data filter on top one and then hide those elements on the 2nd list, which get hidden on the first.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I guess I'll have to go either way.

Comment: so, if you tweak JQM to append the listview filter somewhere else, you can also specify two "target destinations", which will then both receive the same listview filter.